# Microsoft Azure Bot type choices

Tags: azure, bots, chatbot

to create a new bot via Azure, you get 3 options:

1. Web App Bot:
   **An Azure Bot Service Bot deployed to an Azure App Service Web App.** Build, connect, deploy and manage Bots to interact with your users wherever they are - from your app or website to Cortana, Skype, Messenger and many other services.
2. Functions Bot:
   **An Azure Bot Service Bot deployed to an Azure Functions App.** Build, connect, deploy and manage Bots to interact with your users wherever they are - from your app or website to Cortana, Skype, Messenger and many other services.
3. Bot Channels Registration:
   **Your own Bot hosted where you want, registered with the Azure Bot Service.** Build, connect, and manage Bots to interact with your users wherever they are - from your app or website to Cortana, Skype, Messenger and many other services.

Questions:

1. What exactly is the meaning of the highlighted lines, any simple example will be very useful.
2. How do these options matter for a developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully my answer can help you:

- A Web App Bot : This is a standalone Azure web app where you purchase pre-defined capacity for your bot (more suited to an always on with predictable traffic)

  - Edit bot source code online using an advanced in-browser code editor.
  - Download, debug, and re-publish your C# bot using Visual Studio.
  - Set up continuous deployment easily for Visual Studio Online and Github.
  - Use sample code prepared for the Bot Builder SDK.
- A functions bot: This is a bot hosted is Azure functions and uses Functions pay-per-run pricing, this is better suited for bots handling large traffic spikes as it can scale much quicker and efficiently.
- Bot Channels Registration: think of this as a way of publishing a bot not hosted in Azure to the bot service and enable inputs to your bot like cortana and skype connectors.

For a good comparison on Web App (App Service Plan) and Functions (Consumption Plan) bots see this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale

and this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-overview-readme?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

Comment: Can you provide some differences amongst these with regards to bot development. I am trying to understand how these options matter to a developer?

Comment: Sure, the differences I see is more the demand requirements on the bot as detailed below:

Comment: Web App - This has reserved capacity and is more suited to a bot that has a consistent level or traffic and needs reserved performance. A good example of this would be a 24/7 customer service bot that experiences the same amount of traffic throughout the day.

Comment: A functions bot deals on a pay per run and is more suited to bots that have traffic peaks or a relatively low utilised. An example for a functions bot would be a lunch ordering bot that has a huge traffic spike at lunch and otherwise dormant. Functions bot are a pay per run so you dont pay when the bot isn't running as there is no reserved capacity like in a web app

Comment: Bot registration - Think about this as developing an app and publishing it on a store, it is for publishing a bot to a 'Microsoft store' in essence that is already hosted and running elsewhere. This will expand the audience to your bot that is maybe hosted in GCP, AWS, On-premise

Comment: Example of a [functions bot](https://tomasherceg.com/blog/post/building-bots-in-c-with-azure-functions)

Comment: [other examples](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1106457/An-Introduction-to-the-Microsoft-Bot-Framework) and [bot framework documentation] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)

Comment: I have read that the purpose of BOT REGISTRATION type is a special case - that is for example to register a bot application (in azure) that was created in visual studio or other softwares and which was then hosted on azure (web api) or any other web host. The bot registration option allows user to use the hosted bot (via service end point link) in Azure. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: It is for when the bot is hosted on another web host or as something other than a web app or functions app in Azure and allows you to connect that bot to channels supported by bot framework ie. Cortana, Skype, Microsoft Teams, Facebook, Slack. [see more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-3.0). Hope that helps!